# Efficient matrix implementation

Tags: c++

I have the following problem:

- I've a precomputed 2d matrix of values which i need to lookup very often and compute only once
- The size of the matrix is about 4000x4000 at most
- The matrix won't be sparse, i typically need almost all values.
- The values in the matrix can be boolean, integer or double. At least they are always small objects

Currently i am storing the precomputed values in a `std::vector<<std::vector<T>>`, and i've noticed the lookups into this datastructure takes quite some time in heavy computations. I've googled around and so far the suggested implementation seems to be to try a solution in which all the memory is stored contigious using an 1D array where the location in this array is computed based on i and j.

Does anybody have a good example implementation of this or has an even better suggestion? I couldn't find a modern C++ example, while it seems to be a very common problem to me. I'd prefer to use someone elses code instead of reinventing the wheel here. Of course i will measure the differences to see whether it actually improves performance.

Examples i've found:

- https://medium.com/@patdhlk/c-2d-array-a-different-better-solution-6d371363ebf8
- [https://secure.eld.leidenuniv.nl/~moene/Home/tips/matrix2d/](https://secure.eld.leidenuniv.nl/%7Emoene/Home/tips/matrix2d/)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) page soon and also visit the links describing [How to Ask a Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (MCVE). Providing the necessary details, including your MCVE, compiler warnings and associated errors, if any, will allow everyone here to help you with your question. (no, I'm not your downvote)

Comment: If the size is known at compile-time, you could try using a `std::array<std::array<T, Y>, X>`, however using a 1D structure and emulating a 2D one with indexing seems like a good enough idea here. Start with that and see if it resolves your performance issue. Remember to benchmark.

Comment: For fast matrix computations without using a 3rd party library, like Eigen, std::valarray will be your friend. And, C++20 has a constexpr std::vector. Maybe that would help?

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel, use existing optimized libraries.

Answer (score -2):

Here is a very simple and efficient 2-d matrix. The 'main' creates a 10000x10000 double array 'mat', then filled it with random number. The array 'mat' is copied into another array 'mat2'. your may input two integers 'n' and 'm' between 0 and 9999 to fetch the double data at mat2(n,m).

Feel free to use or test it. Let me know if you encounter problems or need some more functions to be implemented. Good luck!

```
#ifndef ytlu_simple_matrix_class_
#define ytlu_simple_matrix_class_
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <complex>
template <typename T> class tMatrix
{
  public:
     T *ptr;
     int col, row, size;
     inline T* begin() const {return ptr;}
     inline T* end() const {return this->ptr + this->size;}
     inline T operator()(const int i, const int j) const { return ptr[i*col+j]; 
} // r-value
     inline T&operator()(const int i, const int j) { return ptr[i*col+j]; } //l-value
     inline tMatrix(): col{0}, row{0}, size{0}, ptr{0} {;}
     tMatrix(const int i, const int j): col(j), row(i), size(i*j)
     {
         ptr = new T [this->size] ;
     }
     tMatrix(const tMatrix<T>&a) : tMatrix<T>(a.row, a.col)
     {
         std::copy(a.begin(), a.end(), this->ptr);
     }
     tMatrix<T>& operator=(tMatrix<T>&&a)
     {
         this->col = a.col;
         this->row = a.row;
         delete [] this->ptr;
         this->ptr = a.ptr;
         a.ptr = nullptr;
         return *this;
     }
     tMatrix<T>& operator=(const tMatrix<T>&a)
     {
       if (col==a.cpl && row==a.row) std::copy(a.begin(), a.end(), this->ptr);
       else { tMatrix<T>&&v(a); *this = std::move(v);}
       return *this;
     }
   ~tMatrix() {delete [] this->ptr;}
}; //end of class tMatrix
template <typename X> std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&p, const tMatrix<X>&a)
{
    p << std::fixed;
    for (int i=0; i<a.row; i++) {
        for (int j=0; j <a.col; j++) p << std::setw(12) << a(i, j);
        p << std::endl;
    }
    return p;
}
using iMatrix = tMatrix<int>;
using rMatrix = tMatrix<double>;
using cMatrix = tMatrix<std::complex<double> >;
#endif
//
//
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
#define N1 10000
int main()
{
    int n, m;
    std:srand(time(NULL));  // randomize
    rMatrix mat(N1, N1);    // declare a 10000 x 10000 double matrix
//
// fill the whole matrix with double random number 0.0 - 1.0
//
   for (int i = 0; i<mat.row; i++)
    { for (int j=0; j<mat.col; j++) mat(i, j) = (double)std::rand() / (double)RAND_MAX; }
//
// copy mat to mat 2 just for test
//
    rMatrix mat2 = mat;
//
// fetch data test input 0 <= n m < 10000 to print mat2(n, m)
//
    while(1)
    {
      std::cout << "Fetch 2d array at (n m) = ";
      std::cin >> n >> m;
      if ((n < 0) || (m < 0) || (n > mat2.row) || (m > mat2.col) )break;
      std::cout << "mat(" << n << ", " << m << ") = " << mat2(n, m) << std::endl << std::endl;
    }
   return 0;
}
```

The compile parameter I used and the test run. It takes a couple seconds to fill the random numbers, and I felt no lapse at all in fetch a data running in my aged PC.

```
ytlu@ytlu-PC MINGW32 /d/ytlu/working/cpptest
$ g++ -O3 -s mtx_class.cpp -o a.exe

ytlu@ytlu-PC MINGW32 /d/ytlu/working/cpptest
$ ./a.exe
Fetch 2d array at (n m) = 7000 9950
mat(7000, 9950) = 0.638447

Fetch 2d array at (n m) = 2904 5678
mat(2904, 5678) = 0.655934

Fetch 2d array at (n m) = -3 4
```

Comment: Identifiers containing two underscores are reserved by the standard to the implementation ([see here](https://eel.is/c++draft/lex.name#3.1)), which means that you must not use them in your own code.

Comment: @DanielKamilKozar I didn't learn this convention. Thank you for this infomation. Post edited.